# How to position a checkbox inside an svg element?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, input

Assume I want to create a small square web element which has circle and a checkbox in the center. Ticking the checkbox should change the colour of the circle. I have provided a working code example below. The problem I currently face is that my current implementation places the checkbox **below** the svg, not **within** it.

**Hence my question**: is there a way to position this tickbox within or above the svg element, and specify its position in terms of percentages of width and height? (e.g., x = width/2, y = height/2)

I expect that this would be a simple problem, but I cannot seem to find a solution - perhaps I am searching for the wrong keywords. I would appreciate any advice!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs/lib/browser/math.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz">
  <svg id="click" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color:#cccccc">
      <defs>

      </defs>
  </svg>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" onclick='check()' id='myCheckbox'>

  <body>
    <script>
    
    // ===================================================
    // Set up basic viewport options
    // ===================================================
    
    // Get viewport sizes
    const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
    const vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0)
      
    // Fit in a square window
    var height  = math.min([vw,vh])*0.75; 
    var width   = math.min([vw,vh])*0.75;

        // Create a svg
    var svg = d3.select("#click") // This selects the div
    .attr("width", width) // This defines the canvas' width
    .attr("height", height) // This defines the canvas' height
    
    // Plot a circle
    svg.append("circle")
      .attr("r", height/4)
      .attr("cx", width/2)
      .attr("cy", height/2)
      .attr("fill", "#ff0000")
      .attr("opacity", 0.75)
      .attr("id","circ");

        // Checking the box changes the color
    function check() {
    
        // If the box is ticked, make the circle green
        if (d3.select("#myCheckbox").property("checked")) {
      
        d3.select("#circ")
            .attr("fill", "#00ff00")
      
      // If the box is not ticked, make the circle red
      } else {
      
        d3.select("#circ")
            .attr("fill", "#ff0000")
      
      }
    }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

EDIT: Following HereticMonkey's suggestion, do you recommend editing the html section as follows?

```
  <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz" position="relative">
  <svg id="click" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color:#cccccc" position="absolute">
      <defs>
      </defs>
  </svg>
      <input type="checkbox" onclick='check()' id='myCheckbox' top="0px"  left="-100px" position="absolute">
</div>
```

Comment: Place the checkbox within the same element as the SVG. Set the containing element to `position: relative` and both the SVG and the checkbox as `position: absolute`. Give the checkbox a `top` and `left` as you see fit.

Comment: You may also wish to read [How to turn a `<circle>` (that's inside an svg) into a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55961820/215552) and its answers.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I am not very experienced with HTML/JavaScript yet. If I parse your comments correctly, do you propose to write:   

(the inline answer breaks the formatting; I have posted the code in an edit above)

This places the tick to the right of the canvas, but it doesn't allow me to create overlapping elements. And the specified "left" property seems inactive. I suppose I have misunderstood your directions?

Comment: Indeed, I am talking about using CSS, not HTML. Use something like `<style>#my_dataviz { position: relative; } #cllick { background-color: #ccc; position: absolute; } #myCheckbox { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 100px; }</style>` within the `<head>` of your document. Note that currently, your `div` and `input` are not within the `<body>`, which is invalid.

Comment: Amazing, that's the solution! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

- ditch D3
- put the HTML in the SVGs `foreignObject`
  finetune positioning with the `x` and `y` attributes
- use the modern CSS `:has` selector to color the `circle` based on the `:checked` state
  not yet supported in FireFox: https://caniuse.com/css-has
  so add your own JS `onclick` *inline Event Handler* to color the circle

### Modern version with `:has` selector

- No JavaScript required

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="height:180px">
  <style>
    svg:has(input:checked) circle {  fill:green  }
    input { zoom: 4 }
  </style>
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="49%" fill="red" />
  <foreignObject x="30%" y="31%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <input type="checkbox" CHECKED> 
  </foreignObject>
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="3" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

### Classic FireFox version

- now requires **two** `CHECKED` settings to set an initial :checked state

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="height:180px">
  <style>
    circle[checked] {  fill:green  }
    input { zoom: 4 }
  </style>
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="49%" fill="red" CHECKED />
  <foreignObject x="30%" y="32%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <input type="checkbox" CHECKED
             onclick="this.closest('svg')
                          .querySelector('circle')
                          .toggleAttribute('checked')"> 
  </foreignObject>
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="3" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey)'s awesome advice, I have got it to work!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs/lib/browser/math.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
        #my_dataviz { position: relative; } 
        #click { background-color: #ccc; position: absolute; } 
        #myCheckbox { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
    </style>
    
  </head>
  
    <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
  <div id="my_dataviz" position="relative">
    <g id="group">
    <svg id="click" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color:#cccccc" position="absolute">
        <defs>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick='check()' id='myCheckbox' top="0px"  left="-100px" position="relative">
    </g>
  </div>


  <body>

    <script>
    
    // ===================================================
    // Set up basic viewport options
    // ===================================================
    
    // Get viewport sizes
    const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
    const vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0)
      
    // Fit in a square window
    var height  = math.min([vw,vh])*0.75; 
    var width   = math.min([vw,vh])*0.75;

        // Create a svg
    var svg = d3.select("#click") // This selects the div
      .attr("width", width) // This defines the canvas' width
      .attr("height", height) // This defines the canvas' height
    
    // Plot a circle
    svg.append("circle")
      .attr("r", height/4)
      .attr("cx", width/2)
      .attr("cy", height/2)
      .attr("fill", "#ff0000")
      .attr("opacity", 0.75)
      .attr("id","circ");
      
        document.getElementById('myCheckbox').style.top = (width/2).toString()+"px";
    document.getElementById('myCheckbox').style.left = (height/2).toString()+"px";

        // Checking the box changes the color
    function check() {
    
        // If the box is ticked, make the circle green
        if (d3.select("#myCheckbox").property("checked")) {
      
        d3.select("#circ")
            .attr("fill", "#00ff00")
      
      // If the box is not ticked, make the circle red
      } else {
      
        d3.select("#circ")
            .attr("fill", "#ff0000")
      
      }
    }
    
      d3.select("#click")
        .append("input")
        .attr("type", "checkbox")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("top", 100)
        .style("left", 100)

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```